# Control access to AWS S3 files from my application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-control

I'm working on an application and we'd like to host our users' files to AWS S3.

Initial thinking is to create a new bucket for every new user (bucket name could be the user's unique code). How can we control access to the user's bucket files using for example his username or email ? S3 provides different levels of access based on a AWS accounts.

We need to make sure that the authenticated user have access to only his bucket files. What would be the best way to achieve this kind of scenario (with S3 or a similar service) and prevent anyone with the right url to access other users files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as though what you're looking to do can be done with [S3 pre-signed urls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

This would require you to:

- Set bucket/file ACL to `private`, which will prevent anyone with "the right url" from accessing the files.
- Allow your application to generate short-term links to files, which your users will then be able to use for access.

Instead of directing your user directly to the file being requested the workflow would be something like the following:

- Direct your user to a route in your application which validates their right to access the desired file.
- Once the user has been authenticated, generated a pre-signed URL for the file requested,
- Return a 302 redirect to that pre-signed URL

Comment: If this pre-signed URL is shared to non-authorised user, it's still accessible, how to overcome this to avoid access ?